# Open a new tab on button click in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="openTab()">new tab</button>

openTab = function () {
  $http.post('www.google.com');
}
```

What I want is post a require and open the response html in a new tab when you click the "openTab" button. There is no method to do this with `$http`.
I think this maybe simple, but I can't find a way.

Comment: Can you accept the solution ? My vote is for @Aaron one :)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can do this all within your controller by using the $window service [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window). $window is a wrapper around the global browser object window.

To make this work inject $window into you controller as follows

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.redirectToGoogle = function(){
            $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        };
    }
]);
```

this works well when redirecting to dynamic routes

Comment: Chrome locks this popup.. How can I recognize it's locked and inform user about it?

Comment: its working fine in chrome and firefox but in IE user get loggedout and redirected to login page.is there some work around to solve the issue for IE

Answer (score 21):

I solved this question this way.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" ng-href="{{url}}" ng-mousedown="openTab()">newTab</a>

$scope.openTab = function() {
    $scope.url = 'www.google.com';
}
```

Comment: This trick is excellent, especially for someone is dealing with the problem that Chrome's security can lock the new tab page which is opened by script manually.

Answer (score 7):

Proper HTML way:
just surround your button with anchor element and add attribute **target="_blank"**. It is as simple as that:

```
<a ng-href="{{yourDynamicURL}}" target="_blank">
    <h1>Open me in new Tab</h1>
</a>
```

where you can set in the controller:

```
$scope.yourDynamicURL = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `$location` service

Angular docs:

- [Guide to using $location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/%24location)
- [$location API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location)

Comment: location doesn't allow you to open a new tab.