# How to navigate on button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have button in anuglarjs and i have bind it with property which contains url. But when i click button i get this error.

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'vm.achReportPath' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{vm.achReportPath}}] starting at [vm.achReportPath}}].

```
<button class="btn btn-default" id="searchFormBtn" data-ng-click="{{vm.achReportPath}}"     type="submit" tabindex="5">View Report</button>

$scope.vm.achReportPath = "www.google.com"
```

Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Check if this helps you: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/19851620/2056394](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19851620/2056394)

Answer (score 0):

replace this

```
  data-ng-click="{{vm.achReportPath}}"
```

with

```
 href="{{vm.achReportPath}}"
```

if you dont have "http://" than

```
   href="http://{{vm.achReportPath}}"
```

Comment: I am not getting any error but its not navigating to url

Comment: so you want to navigate to ggole.com?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of using href with angular is with **ng-href**. href may cause different types of issues. 
ng-href makes sure that the curly braces will be replaced with the value when the element is clicked.