# Angular: Open new tab without popup blocker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I would like to open a `new tab` after `$http` call. Currently, even-though the call is made after user click, popup blocker doesn't allow `new tab` to be created.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
      <button ng-click="openNewTab()">Open new tab</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {

   $scope.openNewTab = function(e) {
       $http.get("test.com").finally(()=>{
         window.open();

       });
    };
}]);
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mKNFlsKclunIKztWXKqh?p=preview)

Comment: Is it me, or it's weird to ask a framework specifically designed to produce single-page applications to open a new window?

Comment: @JeremyThille I am posting relevant data to new tab/URL for subscription processing

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code to open the new tab call the function

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http,$window) {

   $scope.openNewTab = function(e) {
       $http.get("test.com").finally(()=>{
        $window.open('url','_blank');

       });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setInterval out of ajax call where you have to check your variable again and again which will be set in ajax call when condition matches then you can open new tab.

I've also found a workaround for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Demo">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.1" data-semver="2.0.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <button ng-click="doesntWork()">This Doesn't Work</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the angular code:

```
angular.module("Demo", []).controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.doesntWork = function() {
 var isSuccess=0;
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/angular').then(function (result) 
  {       
    isSuccess=1;
  });
 var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (isSuccess!= 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
        if (isSuccess== 1) {
            var newWin = $window.open('', '_blank');
            newWin.location = "https://www.google.co.in";
        }
    },1000);
  };
});
```

Comment: Please give an example of how it should be done. The description of the solution is quite vague.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using the $window service. $window is a wrapper around the global browser object window. Maybe this solves your answer too:
[Open a new tab on button click in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757837/when-click-a-button-then-open-a-new-tab-in-angular-js)

I've also found a workaround for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Demo">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.0.1" data-semver="2.0.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="demo.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <button id="test" ng-click="works()">This Works</button>
    <button ng-click="doesntWork()">This Doesn't Work</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

and the angular code:

```
angular.module("Demo", []).controller("DemoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
  function openInNewTab() {
    var uri = 'http://www.google.nl';
    var link = angular.element('<a href="' + uri + '" target="_blank"></a>');

    angular.element(document.body).append(link);

    link[0].click();
    link.remove();
  };

  $("#test").click(function(){
    openInNewTab();
  });

  $("#test").click();

  $scope.works = openInNewTab;

  $scope.doesntWork = function() {
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/angular').then(openInNewTab);
  };
});
```

Comment: Link only answers should be posted as comments. Since you don't have enough rep to do taht, try to add necessary data from the link to your answer.

Comment: That looks great : )

Comment: @DefermentNL Though it looks great. It still doesn't solve my question :(

Comment: Did you put it in the same plunker? Please keep in mind that I used demo.js in my example and not app.js like you did in your plunker

Comment: @DefermentNL May be you should put your plunker link or modify mine and send the link. I am not getting it to work on my side.

Comment: @DefermentNL You must have allowed popups on the site. When I click on the "Doesn't work" button it straight away blocks the popup. #CHECK

Comment: @ShyamalParikh No, to test my function I used ghostery and set the blocking level on "all" (then it blocks everything). The doesn't work button should be blocked by the add/popup blocker.
This is because If a user triggers the function to open a new url, then pop up blocker will allow it(it should applied to any modern browser - at least firefox, chrome) (this is what you do with the "works button")
If not from user (like javascript function in background, promise or any other function trigger not from user), browser will block unless user whitelist the site manually. (the doesn't work button)

Comment: here is another example to open in a new tab http://plnkr.co/edit/QqsEzMtG5oawZsQq0XBV?p=preview