# Open html on another tab on button click using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a page in my AngularJS that has an edit button, I need to open the edit page on another tab when I click the edit button. Can it be possible using the angular way? I need to use the same controller to be able to access the data. How can I possible do this? Can someone please give me a sample?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open a new tab on button click in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757837/open-a-new-tab-on-button-click-in-angularjs)

Comment: You can use the `$window` service. See the example from the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle to show opening the tab:

https://jsfiddle.net/e8g1m0xs/

I.e.:

```
angular.module('new_tab', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.openTab = function() {
      $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
    };
  }]);

<div ng-app="new_tab" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <button ng-click="openTab()">New Tab</button>
</div>
```

But in order to use the same controller for the new tab, and do something like pass information to it, you would have to implement a wildcard pattern into your angular router to pass along state information. I usually do things like that using UI Router. See the section titled *URL Parameters*.