# How to open `<li>` elements in new tab using query Parameters in Activated Route in Angular

Tags: html, angular, routes, angular4-router

I am having a list of elements say

```
<li [class.active_view]="Display('A')" (click)="Az()">A</li>
<li [class.active_view]="Display('B')" (click)="Bz()">B</li>
<li [class.active_view]="Display('C')" (click)="Cz()">C</li>
```

Currently whenever a user clicks on any of the tab I use

```
this.activatedroute.queryParams.subscribe(query => { 
//some_code_to_set_url
});
```

and then I use this url to navigate to that.
But using `<li>` I am unable to enable `Open in New Tab` option on right click. Is there a way to achieve it using `<li>` tag.(I tried using `href` but it breaks url and replaces many symbols like `?` with `%3F` etc). How to open it in new tab and enable it on right click.

Comment: You can't open in new tab, because it's not a link any more - it's triggering navigation in the background.

Answer (score 0):

That option is only available if you are using `<a>` tags. That's why they are there for. Also, this is semantically incorrect. Say, screen readers and other software that merely go by code, will not be able to access those as links.

Also, to make them open in new tabs, either:

- Change them to `<a>` and give `target="_blank"`.
- Use `window.open()` function to open the URL.

In Angular JS, the `window.open` can be invoked using `$window` service:

```
.controller('exampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$window',
  function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.redirectToGoogle = function(){
      $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
    };
  }
]);
```

Reference: [Open a new tab on button click in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757837)

Comment: Thanks for Answer but I am using Angular not AngularJS.

Comment: @AakashSingh Wait, slightly confused. Just tell the Angular version na?

Comment: It is Angular 4, I know that using `<a></a>` will enable it. But I want to ask that is there a possibility is Angular 4 i.e any router option that can help me in this. Also I tried to do that using `<a routerLink='/search/A'> </a>` and setting route parameters to `{path:'/search/:id,component:ResultComponent}`

Comment: But I was unable to do that.

Comment: @AakashSingh I understand your situation clearly. Unfortunately, even in Angular JS, it's not possible to do that without using `<a>` tags. `:(`

Comment: @PraveenKumar imposible is nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you always can use a work-around (I don't check the code, but my idea is)
in your component

```
<li [class.active_view]="Display('A')" (click)="Az(newpage)">A</li>
<form #newpage [action]="url" target="_blank">
```

Your function Az

```
Az(form:any)
{
    this.url="google";
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me.I think you do not understand the question.