# Angularjs - Open image in a new tab, using "the angular way"

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a `note` object which has a `url`. I need to open this image on click. I've constructed something, it works, but two issues.
First, the image is loaded and shown fine, but chrome keep trying to "load" it, the new tab's title shows "Loading..." with a spinner.
[image]
Second, it does not feel like its "the angular way", is there a better way to handle this situation?

The code:

```
private openImgNewTab(note){

    let image = new Image();
    image.src = note.thumbnailPath;

    var w = window.open("");
    w.document.write(image.outerHTML);
}
```

Comment: You definitely mean AngularJS, not Angular, right? As typescript is normally associated with Angular.

Comment: I mean Angular 1.x

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757837/open-a-new-tab-on-button-click-in-angularjs

Comment: @Collierre TS can be used with AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject the [`$window`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service to get it more "AngularJS-like" then you can do:

`$window.open(.....)`

Answer (score 0):

Here simply you can use the `$window.open(note.thumbnailPath,'_blank')` it should be open the image in new tab.